# Swift Metal Shader Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution when adding a number to an array value

Tags: ios, swift, shader, metal

I'm trying some very simple algorithm using metal GPU acceleration to calculate some values in an array. The shader throws an error under some conditions I will explain.
Error: Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors) (IOAF code 4)

The shader only throws this error when adding a value to the existing value at an index of the array. Example:

This will not cause an error:

```
    kernel void shader (device int *wPointsIntensity [[buffer(0)]],
                const device uint *wPointsXCoord [[buffer(1)]],
                const device uint *wPointsYCoord [[buffer(2)]],
                device float *pixelSignalIntensity [[buffer(3)]],
                device float *pixelDistance [[buffer(4)]],
                const device uint& noOfPoints [[ buffer(5) ]],
                const device uint& width [[ buffer(6) ]],
                const device uint& height [[ buffer(7) ]],
                uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {

//this does not throw error
for (uint wpIndex = 0; wpIndex < noOfPoints; wpIndex++) {
    for (uint heightIndex = 0; heightIndex < height; heightIndex++) {
        for (uint widthIndex = 0; widthIndex < width; widthIndex++) {

            uint pixelIndex = heightIndex * width + widthIndex;
            pixelDistance[pixelIndex] = float(pixelIndex);
            pixelSignalIntensity[pixelIndex] = float(pixelIndex);
}}}}
```

While if you change

pixelDistance[pixelIndex] = float(pixelIndex); 
with

pixelDistance[pixelIndex] += float(pixelIndex);

It will throw an error.

Here is the swift code:

```
var wPointsValues = [Int32](repeating:0, count: wPoints.count)
var wPointsXLocations = [Int32](repeating:0, count: wPoints.count)
var wPointsYLocations = [Int32](repeating:0, count: wPoints.count)
        for i in 0..<wPoints.count {
            wPointsValues[i] = Int32(wPoints[i].signalIntensity)
            wPointsXLocations[i] = Int32(wPoints[i].location.x)
            wPointsYLocations[i] = Int32(wPoints[i].location.y)
        }

        var numberOfWPoints:Int32 = Int32(wPoints.count)
        var int32Width = Int32(width)
        var int32Height = Int32(height)

        //output arrays

        let numberOfResults = wPoints.count * Int(width) * Int(height)
        var wPointsSignalIntensity = [Float32](repeating:0.0, count: numberOfResults)
        var wPointsDistance = [Float32](repeating:0.0, count: numberOfResults)


        //local variables
        var signalDensity:[Float32] = [Float32](repeating:0.0, count: numberOfResults)
        var signalDistance:[Float32] = [Float32](repeating:0.0, count: numberOfResults)

            //create input buffers
            let inWPointSignalValues = device.makeBuffer(bytes: wPointsValues, length: (MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride * wPoints.count), options: [])
            let inWPointXCoordBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: wPointsXLocations, length: (MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride * wPoints.count), options: [])
            let inWPointYCoordBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: wPointsYLocations, length: (MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride * wPoints.count), options: [])

            //create putput buffers
            let outPixelSignalIntensityBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: wPointsSignalIntensity, length: (MemoryLayout<Float32>.stride * numberOfResults), options: [])
            let outPixelDistanceBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: wPointsDistance, length: (MemoryLayout<Float32>.stride * numberOfResults), options: [])

            let commandBuffer = (mtlCommmandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer())!
            let computeCommandEncoder = (commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder())!
            computeCommandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(mtlComputePipelineFilter!)
            //set input buffers
            computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(inWPointSignalValues, offset: 0, index: 0)
            computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(inWPointXCoordBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
            computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(inWPointYCoordBuffer, offset: 0, index: 2)

            //set output buffers
            computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(outPixelSignalIntensityBuffer, offset: 0, index: 3)
            computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(outPixelDistanceBuffer, offset: 0, index: 4)

            //set constants
            computeCommandEncoder.setBytes(&numberOfWPoints, length: MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride, index: 5)
            computeCommandEncoder.setBytes(&int32Width, length: MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride, index: 6)
            computeCommandEncoder.setBytes(&int32Height, length: MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride, index: 7)


            let threadsPerGroup = MTLSize(width:2,height:2,depth:2)
            let numThreadgroups = MTLSize(width:2, height:2, depth:2)
            computeCommandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(numThreadgroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerGroup)

            let endBufferAllocation = mach_absolute_time()

            print("time for creating and setting buffert: time: \(Double(endBufferAllocation - start) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))")
            computeCommandEncoder.endEncoding()

            commandBuffer.commit()
            commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
            let allComplete = mach_absolute_time()
        self.signalDistance = (outPixelDistanceBuffer?.contents())!
        self.signalDensity = (outPixelSignalIntensityBuffer?.contents())!
```

Comment: Hmm. You're using more buffers than necessary. You could consolidate your inputs and the uniforms into structs. Also, the `const device` ones, in this case, can be `constant` instead. In any case, you are causing all of the compute threads to do the same work. They are probably doing it in lockstep. So, all of the threads are simultaneously doing the increment of `pixelDistance[pixelIndex]`, which, at the very least, will produce undefined results. It's quite possibly the source of the error, too.

Comment: The main benefit of GPU acceleration is parallelism, making the threads do separate parts of the problem. If you split up the work, based on the thread ID, you'll get better performance and also maybe avoid the error.

Comment: After commandBuffer.commit call draw()

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for ages and program crashed intermittently. It turned out that I was accessing memory in the kernel that had not been allocated by the buffer. In the kernel I was doing a for loop 0..<5 (i.e. output 5 values for each thread) but had not divided the num_threads by 5.

When it didn't crash it was giving the correct answer and no errors except " Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)" were ever thrown.